# Abort the function call if it running in multiple threads

Tags: java, javascript, multithreading, jsp, session-timeout

I am setting a sessionTimeout function in my jsp page where I call the other Jsp page using an iframe on a click of a button In the other jsp page also I have this sessionTimeout function. Because of this the function is running in parallel. Can anyone help me if there is any way "if the same function is called multiple times in different threads  then it should cancel the all other thread and access for the latest thread".

I have tried using synchronised method but it wont allow me to use until the function is completed So I cant use the synchronise

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: assign a variable to the sessionTimeout. If it is not null then the process is running. Once the process has completed then reset the variable to null.

Comment: but if my quetion is that if the function is called at two places one after the other as the case i have explained in my question I need only the latest thread to be working and the remaining threads should be aborted

Comment: Because the variable is not null then other processes can't/shouldn't use the process.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript running in different iframe are not guaranteed to run in same thread for each browser engine implementation.

You might need to build a task management utility in parent window to keep track of iframe instances and sessionTimeout function running state (keep the state in a array/map). Since script inside parent and all iframes are single threaded in their context, you can check the state of each iframe before you fire sessionTimout function in iframes.

In case you need cross-domain iframe communication, you can read this post at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585663/Communication-with-Cross-Domain-IFrame-A-Cross-Bro